# jquery timepicker opening date time picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

I am using jquery UI datetime picker for selecting date and time. In a particular requirement I just need to select Time from the input field. So i tried to use the following method.

```
$("#inputtext").timepicker();
```

where as the html for the inputtext is as follows:

```
<input class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left ui-corner-right" name="inputtext" id="inputtext">
```

But this opens up entire jquery date time picker.

Can you please let me know how can I disable date picker?
Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I have both jquery and jquery-ui imported.

Comment: check it's working fine http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/g5CAY/

Comment: @TusharGupta Sorry.. but the script doesn't seem to be working for me in mozilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see such thing for the first time. Datepicker and timepicker are separate controls in my project. Maybe you're using not default timepicker of jQuery. If so, you can try this:

```
$("#inputtext").timepicker({
    timeOnly: true
});
```

Reference: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/